# How to add vertical scroll to my React material table?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, material-table

I want to add vertical scroll if my data is too long. Horizontal scroll is working fine is data is too large but I am not getting how to vertical scroll in material table in react typescript ?

My code is -

```
{isLoading ?
        (<Spinner></Spinner>)
        : error && error.length > 0 ?
          (<ErrorDetails error={error}></ErrorDetails>)
          : result && (<div className={classes.root}>
            {result && result.length > 0 ?
              (<><MaterialTable
                icons={icons}
                columns={columns}
                data={result}
                options={{
                  exportButton: true,
                  sorting: true,
                  search: false,
                  paging: false,
                  fixedColumns: {
                    left: 2,
                  },
                  toolbar: false
                }}
              /> <section className={classes.rightToolbar}>
                  <Link className={classes.a} to="/scenarioDetails">
                    <OutlinedButtons></OutlinedButtons>
                  </Link>
                </section></>)
              : (<NoRecords></NoRecords>)}
          </div>)}</>)
```

I have not added horizontal scroll but still it's working fine. But I wanna add vertical scroll so how can I get it done ?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `maxBodyHeight` property, which will create vertical scrollbar if data exceeding the given height.

```
<MaterialTable
    options={{
      maxBodyHeight: 400,
    }}
/>
```

Comment: That was a helpful answer to fix the height of table body. Is there a way to fix the location of table navigation bar (next, last, first, etc..). It means, having the scrollbar just over the navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

It's not up to MaterialTable props/settings. You might want to place the table within fixed height HTMLElement

Comment: so how can I fix height in this case ?

Comment: It's based on your layout. The table will now take as much space as the data needs. In order to have a vertical scrollbar you would have to limit table's container height.